# GAE jpa database model example

Tags: database, google-app-engine, jpa

I am totally new at this, I am sorry if it is stupid question.

I am trying to design database model for Google App Engine in JPA, but I am unable to get it right. When I find the way I can't get annotations right or I am getting error about M:N not supported in Google App Engine.

I need entity user to have multiple groups and groups have multiple users and there are users who are also group admins.

My basic model was `User -> usergroup(user; group; (bool)isAdmin) <-Group`

Can somebody give a clean and simple example of how to define relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private UserGroup usergroup;
}
```

class userGroup

```
@Entity
public class UserGroup {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;
    private String name;
    private boolean admin;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "usergroup", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
}
```

please be noticed GAE have limitation on JPA you can read more [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2)

Comment: I dont understand why UserGroup should have multiple users List, how do I tell who is admin.

Comment: i'm not sure why user dont have the userGroup. But you can check is that user exist in list of users in entity userGroup admin.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Google App Engine, but I can help with JPA though.

The problem here is the "isAdmin" column, which prevents the data model to be a simple @ManyToMany relationship with a joiner table.

With the introduction of this field, in the data model you need a Map on the User entity with key=Group and value=isAdmin, similarly you need a corresponding Map in the Group entity in order to know if each User is an admin.

This is modeled with @ElementCollection in the following way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.TABLE)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="Users_Groups", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="userId")})
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="groupId")
    @Column(name="isAdmin")
    private Map<Group, Boolean> groups;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="Group")
public class Group
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.TABLE)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="Users_Groups", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="groupId")})
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="userId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @Column(name="isAdmin", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Map<User, Boolean> users;
}
```

The important annotation is @ElementCollection, the other annotations are just to name the specific columns of the collection table and make sure they match from both entities: @CollectionTable gives the name of the table and the name of the column representing the id in the current entity. @MapKeyJoinColumn gives the name of the column representing the id of the "key" element in the Map, and @Column gives the name of the "value" element in the map.

I'm not sure if the insertable=false and updatable=false are needed in one of the entities, might avoid adding duplicate rows due to the cyclic dependency between User and Group.

Also you need to manually create the collection table, because at least EclipseLink tries to create it with two "groupId" and "isAdmin" columns. You might consider reviewing the design if it is absolutely needed a cyclic dependency between User and Group.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but i was trying to model ManyToMany and got unsupported exception.

Comment: I can't imagine how to have an "isAdmin" column in a ManyToMany relationship. If you forget about the tables and relational model, and only care about the object model you need, how do the java classes look like?